# C# Regex to match multiple section

Tags: c#, regex

I have a .txt file with this format

> **content-length: 20**
>
> blahblahblah
> *-stop-*
>
> **content-length: 10**
>
> bum
> *-step-*
>
> **content-length: 0**
>
> <---empty space--->
> *-step-*
>
> **content-length: 10**
>
> huba
> *-step-*

I use regex to separate the section per content length, which is use step or stop to make it become end of the section. My regex is

> *((content-length:)\s(\d*)[\r\n]+([\s\S]+?)(-stop-|-step-))*

However, if the content length is zero which means before step or stop there is whitespace, it also capture the next content length section. Any idea to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with the following regex, not sure if it is what you want:

```
var pattern = @"(content-length:\s\d+(?:[\s\S]*?)?-(?:stop|step)-)";
var input = @"content-length: 20

    blahblahblah
    -stop-
    content-length: 10

    bum
    -step-
    content-length: 0


    -step-
    content-length: 10

    huba
    -step-";
var result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Man for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?:(?:content-length):\s(?<length>\d+)\n+(?<content>.*?)\n*(?:-stop-|-step-))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF2bT8/1)

Input:

```
content-length: 20

blahblahblah
-stop-
content-length: 10

bum
-step-
content-length: 0


-step-
content-length: 10

huba
-step-
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
length  [16-18] `20`
content [20-32] `blahblahblah`
MATCH 2
length  [56-58] `10`
content [60-63] `bum`
MATCH 3
length  [87-88] `0`
2.  [91-91] ``
MATCH 4
length  [114-116]   `10`
content [118-122]   `huba`
```

Answer (score 0):

[try this](https://regex101.com/r/kI1uX9/2):

`(?:(?:content-length:))\s(\d+)[\r\n]+(.*)?[\r\n]+(?:-stop-|-step-)`

Answer (score 0):

((content-length:)\s(\d+)[\r\n]+(.*)\n*(-stop-|-step-)). 
Check out the regex here https://regex101.com/r/wU9uA4/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
((content-length:)\s(\d)[\r\n]\*([\s\S]\*?)(-stop-|-step-))
```